# Align first line in tikz picture with surrounding text

Tags: tikz-pgf, vertical-alignment

I would like to align the baseline of the first row of the tikzpicture with the baseline of the surrounding text to get something like

```
Let A → B    be a function from A to B
    a → f(a)
```

but at the moment, the tikzpicture is centered vertically. My code is

```
Let
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=-2.6pt,description/.style={fill=white,inner sep=2pt}]
\matrix (m) [matrix of math nodes, row sep=0em, column sep=2em, text height=1.75ex, text depth=.25ex, column 2/.style={anchor=base west}]
{
A & B \\
a & f(a) \\
};
\path[->]
(m-1-1) edge node[above] {$f$} (m-1-2);
\path[|->]
(m-2-1) edge (m-2-2);
\end{tikzpicture}
be a function from A to B.
```

Comment: Please always post a *complete* MWE which people can copy-paste-compile. That is much more useful than a fragment of code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You get what you want with `aligned`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

Let
$\!\begin{aligned}[t]
  A &\overset{f}{\longrightarrow} B\\
  a &\longmapsto f(a)\end{aligned}$
be a function from $A$ to $B$.

\end{document}
```

But it's better not having such big objects inline. I'd much prefer

```
Let $f\colon A\to B$, $a\mapsto f(a)$, be a function from $A$ to $B$.
```

Setting the assignment on a different line adds no information and spoils the spacing.

[image]

If you insist in doing it with TikZ, here it is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\begin{document}

Let
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  baseline=(m-1-1.base),
  description/.style={fill=white,inner sep=2pt}
]
\matrix (m) [
  matrix of math nodes,
  row sep=0em,
  column sep=2em,
  text height=1.75ex,
  text depth=.25ex,
  column 2/.style={anchor=base west}]
  {
   A & B \\
   a & f(a) \\
  };
  \path[->] (m-1-1) edge node[above] {$\scriptstyle f$} (m-1-2);
  \path[|->] (m-2-1) edge (m-2-2);
\end{tikzpicture}
be a function from $A$ to $B$.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Fantastic, thank you! I gave my reason for using tikz on the answer by wipet: I want to align the entries (center- and left-align) and have tikz auto-adjust the length of the two arrows.

Comment: @Earthliŋ I warmly suggest you not to do like this: it makes your document look bad. Really.

Comment: OK, well, thank you for your advice, but I prefer my method. Just imagine R³ x R² → B \\ (a, b, c), (d, e) → f (a, ..., d). Right-aligning the first column just looks awful.

Comment: @Earthliŋ The bad thing is using this notation inline as opposed to a display.

Comment: Oh, if it makes you feel better, I'm using it inline on a single line in an enumerate item. Using display there would just add too much space around everything.

Comment: [It's pretty](http://imgur.com/viH5j8s). I just need to cut the whitespace around `tikzpicture`.

Answer (score 2):

We, users of plain TeX, don't need `tikz` for such example:

```
Let
\vtop{\halign{$\hfil#{}$&$#\hfil$\cr
    A \buildrel f\over\longrightarrow& B\cr
    a \longmapsto& f(a)\cr}}
be a function from $A$ to $B$.

\bye
```

Comment: Nice, but I would like to (1) use tikz arrows (since I use them throughout my document) and, more importantly, (2) align the first column in the its center and the second column at its left, which I find the most beautiful alignment for entries of different lengths. I figured the natural solution for me would be to use tikzpicture.